# How to get the output of this C program?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
int a[3][5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
int *p[] = {*a, *(a + 1) , *(a + 2) };
int (*ptr)[5];
ptr = a;
printf ("%d\n", *(*(p + 1) + 1));
printf ("%d %d %d\n", ** ptr , *(*( ptr + 1) + 2) , *(*( ptr + 2) + 3));
printf ("%d %d %d\n", ptr [0][0] , ptr [1][2] , ptr [2][3]) ;
return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
7
1 8 14
1 8 14
```

Can someone explain this program step by step? Really confused...

Comment: And what Part are you confused with?

Comment: Single step through it with your favourite debugger and find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example for this line:

```
printf ("%d\n", *(*(p + 1) + 1));
```

Look at that line:

```
int *p[] = {*a, *(a + 1) , *(a + 2) };
```

So `p` is pointer (array) to integer pointers with some address and value `*a` at initial index.

Then `(p + 1)` is next address of `p` and its value `*(p + 1)` is pointer `*(a + 1)`

Next, `a` is two dimension array and `(a + 1)` is array of addresses for values `6, 7, 8, 9, 10`

Therefore `*(p + 1)` is address for value 6 and `*(p + 1) + 1` is address for value 7.

So we get: `*(*(p + 1) + 1)` is integer value from address for value 7, i.e.

```
printf ("%d\n", *(*(p + 1) + 1));
```

returns `7`

Try to figure out the rest of code. Same method.